# Getting "process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });" error while issuing model.save() function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am building a Mean Stack app with mongo as backend. 
I have a church schema in my mongoose model which looks like this:

```
{
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var sequenceGenerator = require('mongoose-sequence-plugin');

var unit = new Schema({
    unit_id: {type: String},
    unit_name:  {type: String, unique: true},
    unit_address: {type: String}
});

var schema = new Schema({
    church_id: {type: String},
    church_name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email:     {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    parishname: {type: String},
    diocese: {type: String},
    units: [unit],
    church_reg_id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    address: {type: String},
    city: {type: String},
    zipcode: {type: Number},
    state: {type: String},
    church_contact_no: {type: Number}
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);
schema.plugin(sequenceGenerator, {
    field: 'church_id',
    startAt: '0001',
    prefix: 'CHURCH_',
    maxSaveRetries: 3
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Church', schema);
```

Now i am trying to update the units sub-document in my current schema which is already having data for other fields. Code for updating as is below:

```
router.patch('/addunit/:uname/:uaddress', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.params.uname);
    Church.findOne({church_id: req.body.church_id}, function (err, church) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'No Church Details Found',
                error: err
            });
        }

        console.log(church.church_reg_id);
        console.log(church.church_name);
        church.units.push({
           unit_name: req.params.uname,
            unit_address: req.params.uaddress,
            unit_id: req.body.church_id + "Unit_" + req.params.uname
        });
        console.log(church.units);

        church.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occured',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Unit Added',
                obj: result
            })
        });

    });
});
```

Now the issue is the code runs successfully and the units field is updated successfully in the backend but I am getting below error after this.

```
 D:\Church\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at D:\Church\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:267:5


     at D:\Church\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:195:9
        at handleCallback (D:\Church\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
        at D:\Church\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1062:5
        at D:\Church\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Kindly please help in pinpointing the issue.

Comment: Code seems bugfree, I think the issue is in different code file.

Comment: @JiteshTukadiya Thanks for the response.

Actually i had a line in my app.js file  as  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

When i commented out the line i am getting below error:-

(node:6480) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
D:\Church\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
TypeError: callback is not a function
   

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to successfully update the document using findOneAndUpdate query and using $addToSet to add the sub-docs in the church schema.

```
 Church.findOneAndUpdate({church_id: req.body.church_id}, update1, options, function (err, church) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            title: 'An error occured',
                            error: err
                        });
                    }
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: 'Unit Added',
                        obj: church
                    })
                });
```

Still not sure why model.save() query was throwing error.